# Change wp_sanitize function?

Tags: domain, sanitization

I have a domain name like `sép`. `wp_sanitize` functions clears the `é`character. I would like to change it, but I cannot redeclare in functions.php.

Is it possible to change, or WordPress cannot run under my domain?

Comment: Which functions precisely do you mean? _How_ do they interact with your domain?

Comment: wp_sanitize_redirect. It is a pluggable function, and I can replace it in a plugin, but I cannot in theme. Is it possible to replace this function in function.php of my theme?